# Can I withdraw funds from an empty smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts

I've stuffed up bad and managed to send some Tez to an empty KT1 smart contract.

Is there any way of getting it back?

The contract is:

```
parameter string;
storage string;
code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR }
```

and it is marked as not spendable.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide more details. It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "empty KT smart contract"?

Comment: The contract is "parameter string;
storage string;
code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR }" and it is marked as not spendable

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to say that the intended behavior, as of protocol 004_Pt24m4xi, is that it is impossible to recover tez sent to such contracts.

It is at least conceivable that a future protocol might detect similar obviously(?) broken contracts, prohibiting new examples and unlocking the tez somehow for existing examples.